# Monitor file read on Windows - C# solution

Tags: c#, file, kernel, hook

I want to know when files inside a specific folder are being opened by a process.
I've been told to hook to windows kernel events, but how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` Class

*Use FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in a specified directory. You can watch for changes in files and subdirectories of the specified directory. You can create a component to watch files on a local computer, a network drive, or a remote computer.*

more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: But FileSystemWatcher enables me to monitor only changes on files, not simple reads. I need to know when the process OPEN the file for reading.

Comment: in your question you said :"...being opened by a process"